# I want to reuse most of the visible part of a parent activity in two different types of child activities

Tags: java, android

In my application the user can view their own profile and they can view another user's profile. They are 80% identical so I want to use a base activity that these two extend and only implement the differences.

The child activity gets on top of the parent activity and hides all the data that I've set - the texts and the user avatar. I CAN NOT make it transparent/transluscent/dialog-like using themes, because Im forced to use SherlockActivity that does not support those for some reason :(

Maybe the whole pattern im using is wrong, so what could I do? I dont want to go back to having two different activities that have 80% duplicate code for MyProfile and UserProfile...

My current implementation is as follows

in some activity the user clicks My Profile:

```
Intent goToUserProfile = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class);
goToUserProfile.putExtra("currentUser", true);
startActivity(goToUserProfile);
```

In My Profile:

```
public class MyProfile extends PersonProfile implements OnClickListener, OnChangeUserQuoteListener {

    // Change user quote dialog and its XML components (only the additional controls are added)
    private Dialog changeUserQuoteDialog;
    private EditText etChangeUserQuoteContent;
    private Button bChangeUserQuoteSubmit;
    private Button bChangeUserQuoteCancel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            identifyUser(extras); //identifyUser is a method in PersonProfile, the superclass (I will add it below)
        }

        // Set OnClick Listeners - these are the ones that are different in MyProfile compared to UserProfile
        bUserProfileActionButtonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        bUserProfileActionButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvUserProfileStatsAreVisibleNote.setOnClickListener(this);
        iUserAvatar.setOnClickListener(this);


    } // End of onCreate Method
```

In PersonProfile (the superclass)

```
public class PersonProfile extends SlidingMenuAndActionBar implements OnClickListener, OnGetUserDataFromServerListener {

    // set up XML View Components
    protected TextView tvUserName;
    protected TextView tvUserQuote;
    protected TextView tvMoneySpent;

    // Variables holding data
    protected UserExtended userExtendedData;
    protected boolean currentUser;
    protected int personId;
    protected String personName;
    protected String personSex;
    protected String personEmail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Assign and inflate an XML file as the view component for this screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_user_profile);

        // Assign java objects to XML View elements
        tvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
        tvUserStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserStatus);
        tvMoneySpent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoneySpent);




        // Set onClickListeners
        tvUserProfileItemsTab.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvUserProfileCommentsTab.setOnClickListener(this);

    } // End of onCreate

    // if its some other user's profile we are looking at.
    private void handleUserDetails(UserExtended userExtendedData) {
        personName = userExtendedData.getUserName();
        personSex = userExtendedData.getUserSex();
        personEmail = userExtendedData.getUserEmail();
        personAvatarPath = userExtendedData.getUserAvatarPath();
        personQuote = userExtendedData.getUserQuote();
         ...
    }

    // if the user is looking at their own profile, we are using the global variables that hold their data
    private void handleUserDetails() {
        personName = userName;
        personSex = userSex;
        personEmail = userEmail;
   ....


    }

    protected void setDisplayedData() {
        // Set displayed text
        bUserProfileActionButtonOne.setText(String.valueOf(personPoints) + " points");
        tvUserProfileItemsTab.setText("[" + personItemsCount + "] Items");
        tvUserProfileCommentsTab.setText("[" + personCommentsCount + "] Comments");


        // Set user display name
        tvUserName.setText(personName);

        // Set user quote
        tvUserQuote.setText(personQuote);

        // Set user status
        setUserStatus(personPoints);
        tvUserStatus.setText(personStatus);


    } // End of SetDisplayData

    protected void identifyUser(Bundle extras) {

        currentUser = extras.getBoolean("currentUser", false);
        personId = extras.getInt("userId", currentlyLoggedInUser);

        if (currentUser) {

            handleUserDetails();
            setDisplayedData();

        } else {

            new GetUserDataFromServerAsync(String.valueOf(personId), PersonProfile.this, PersonProfile.this).execute();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetUserDataFromServerSuccess(UserExtended userDetailsAndStats) {
        userExtendedData = userDetailsAndStats;
        handleUserDetails(userExtendedData);
        setDisplayedData();

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetUserDataFromServerFailure(String reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

} // End of Class
```

Comment: One activity which takes userid, if it's -1 load current user if not load the id. Then if you need two differents layout add two setcontentviews and try to keep ids the same.

Comment: well 80% (even more) of the layout is the same? and if it is one activity I should make lots of checks if(currentUser)

Comment: Why? You can use "general variables" I mean.. what is the differences between? If they show the same thing generalizate everything just change the source from where it comes

Comment: my profile has buttons "settings" and "points". user profile has buttons "add friend" and "message". My profile has the ability to change user's avatar. user profile has the ability for the avatar to be viewed and commented on. and so on so forth... there are functional differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create a view layout for your User profile, with all the widgets needed for your user and for other users.

Then you have a class MyProfile which inflates the layout, shows all widgets important for your MyUser and hides the others. Then create another class OtherUserProfile which loads the same layout, but shows only the widgets important for your OtherUser and hides the widgets for MyUser.

You should/could wrap those views in a fragment and show the fragment depending on what user is clicked.

Edit:

The base class :

```
public abstract class Profile extends RelativeLayout {

public Profile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initImpl();
}

final private void initImpl() {
    ((LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.view_profile, this, true);
    init();
}

protected abstract void init();
```

}

The user class :

```
public class UserProfile extends Profile {

public UserProfile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    findViewById(R.id.tvOther).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

The other user class :

```
public class OtherProfile extends Profile {

public OtherProfile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    findViewById(R.id.tvUser).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Now you know what I mean?

Comment: this way I'd have to findViewById twice, and have userName, userSex and so on twice. is there no way that I can reuse most of an activity's code